# How do I construct a function in order to calculate the max value of one of the functions variable?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization, convex-optimization, economics

Hopefully, the title isn't too confusing.
I have two questions. The first is based on economic theory, but it's really a math question.

**Q1: Maximize Government tax revenue**

The goal is to maximize Government tax revenue. We are given a labour supply function:

$$l = w(1-t)$$

where l is labour supply, w is the wage and t is the tax (a number between 0 and 1).
Then we are asked to construct a Government revenue function (GR) and calculate the tax rate that produces the highest income for the government.

The answer is $$GR = t * w(1-t)$$

And if we take the partial derrivate of $GR$ w.r.t $t$, we get $t^* = {1 \over 2}$, where $t^*$ is the optimal tax-rate.

I realize that the answer gives us the value for t that gives us the maximum pint of a parabola.
However, **my question is**: why is the government revenue function not simply $GR = t*w$? So, for example, if the wage is 100 USD and the tax is 20%, the government revenue will be $0.2*100 = 20usd$. If I didn't know the correct answer that would be my guess. What's the initiative way to understand the logic of this equation?

**Q2: Tips on reading material**

I would really appreciate if someone could recommend me some reading material to help me (and others) develop some intuition for this. Preferably with some theory and problems that let me practice creating functions. I don't have any formal maths training, so nothing to advanced I guess...

Comment: It seems your first question is in economics and not in mathematics? (I'm guessing they multiplied by $t$ because the government gets only that percentage out of the salary.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's more of a mathematics question as I want to know the intuition behind the mathematical equation and not the economic theory. As to why it's multiplied by t, you are correct - but why then do we multiply by t twice?

Comment: They only multiply by $t$ once. The function is $\ell=w(1-t)$ and that is considered part of the problem that is given. Asking why this specific $\ell$ makes sense in the real world is definitely a matter of factors which are outside of mathematics itself. My guess for why it makes sense that $\ell$ would be described by such a formula with a factor of $1-t$ is that the higher the tax the less incentive the worker has to work more hours, but I could be wrong, I'm unfamiliar with most of the economics terms in your question. The real point is that this formula is just a given in the question.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. In the government revenue function, they multiply by $t$ two times: $GR=t∗w(1−t)$. As for $\ell = w(1-t)$, you are right about the theory- -higher tax = lower incentives to work (although I should note that this is just a very simplified model, that does not make a lot of sense in the real world).

Comment: If we consider $\ell$ as given then from that to $GR$ we only multiply by $t$ once. The $\ell$ we should consider as given in the question and not doubt its correctness. If we look at the overall expression for $GR$ then it does make sense that it has both a factor of $t$ and $1-t$ because the higher $t$ is the less hours the worker is going to put in (so $GR$ should become lower, hence the $1-t$), and on the other hand the higher $t$ is the more the government earns (hence the $t$ term).

Comment: I think maybe you are right here. I think part of the confusion on my part is that I didn't realize fully the different role the factors $t$ and $1-t$ play in this equation. I guess one way to reformulate what you just wrote is to say that the function GR is increasing in $t$ and decreasing in (1-t).... (right!?)

Comment: I can see why you'd want to say that but it's not quite true. If it were just for the $t$ term by itself then $GR$ would be increasing with $t$, and if it were just for $1-t$ then $GR$ would be decreasing in $t$, but as they appear together the situation is more complicated: for $t>\frac{1}{2}$ the function is decreasing as $t$ increases, for $t<\frac{1}{2}$ the function is increasing as $t$ increases -- this follows from your analysis that the maximum is at $t=\frac{1}{2}$. You can also look at the graph of $f(x)=x(1-x)$ which is a parabola https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+x-x%5E2

Comment: Thank you so much for you time! This makes perfect sense!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The government maximizes total tax revenue which are given by
\begin{align}
GR=t\ell(t),
\end{align}
where $\ell(t)$ is a function of the tax. The level of $t$ that maximizes $GR$ is then simply
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial GR}{\partial t}=0
\end{align}
Computing this derivative, we obtain
\begin{align}
\ell(t)+t\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial t}=0
\end{align}
That is a general expression and makes intuitive sense. A higher $t$ leads to higher tax revenues if labour supply is costant, but it also discourages labour supply since workers get less money for their work (and so we expect $\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial t}<0$).

To obtain the solution in your question, simply note that $\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial t}=-w$. Substituting this in and solving yields the desired solution ($t^{\ast}=1/2$).